# Credentials not available in Jenkins Pull Request Builder plugin

Tags: jenkins

I have added global credentials in Jenkins.

However when I try to add then in my Pull Request builder plugin configuration, they don't seem available.

Any suggestions?

Using Jenkins 2.303.1

(the arrow on the left of the Add drop-down does not do anything)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions in the GitHub pull request builder plugin documentation says that you need to "select `Kind` -> `Secret text`".  Based on the icon in your  credentials list, I think you have defined a credential type "Private key".

The pull request builder likely uses the GitHub API's to perform many of its operations.  GitHub API's rely on a username and a personal access token.  They generally do not support a private key as the credential.

Define a secret text credential as described in the [online help](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/#documentation).